# Sard theorem for locally Lipschitz functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Is there a kind of  Sard's Theorem for locally Lipschitz functions?

Comment: Not sure there's really a direct analogue to Sard's theorem in general here but the area and coarea formula in geometric measure theory are kind of along those lines, and in the special case of equal dimension between domain and target the area formula generalizes Sard's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_formula_(geometric_measure_theory)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula